# How to remove labels from string?

Tags: php, regex, replace

Consider the following:

```
$string = "A string with {LABELS} and {more|232} {lbls} and some other stuff";
echo str_replace('/(\{.*?\})/', '', $string);
```

I'm trying to remove all labels (a label is any text between `{brackets}`). The expected output was:

```
A string with and and some other stuff
```

But what I get was the original string:

```
A string with {LABELS} and {more|232} {lbls} and some other stuff
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your 2 strings in your question are the same !?!?!

Comment: your expected and actual results look same.

Comment: I see no difference between expected and original.

Comment: You are right, my bad :) See the edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

str_replace doesnt work with regular expressions, use preg_replace instead:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `preg_replace` instead:

```
$string = "A string with {LABELS} and {more|232} {lbls} and some other stuff";
echo preg_replace( '/\{.*?\}/', '', $string );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo preg_replace('/\{.*?\}/', '', $string);
```

Comment: This will match everything between the first `{` and the last `}` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\{.*?\}/','',$str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use preg_replace, but *also* you need a slightly different regex to filter out spaces and make sure you're matching the curly braces properly

```
$string = "A string with {LABELS} and {more|232} {lbls} and some other stuff";
echo preg_replace('/\s*\{[^}]*\}/', '', $string);
```

Gives: A string with and and some other stuff